# Unbounded operator can not be extended

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

[Densely Defined Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densely_defined_operator)

In this wiki link, it gives the definition of densely defined operator. After the definition, it gives an example of a densely defined unbounded operator, differentiation operator on $C^0[0,1]$. First, the differentiation is well-defined in $C^1[0,1]$

My question is why
"This unboundedness causes problems if one wishes to somehow continuously extend the differentiation operator D to the whole of $C^0([0, 1]; R)$.'' What problem would we have when trying to extend the differentiation operator?

Comment: How would you propose to define an extension? The method for bounded operators is  an approximation argument

Comment: I am not clear how wiki defines the continuous extension too.  Could we do the same approximation process for the unbounded operator?

Comment: Say you want to define it at $u\notin D(A)$. Then you take $u_n\to u$ and try to use completeness of the image:
$$ \| Au_n - Au_m \| \to 0?$$
if this is true, then $Au_n$ would be Cauchy in a complete space and therefore converges to *something*. Call that $Au$ and then check it works.

This rests on the convergence to 0, which in turn is usually by *boundedness*
$$ \| A v\| \le C\|v\|$$

Comment: I understand that we need boundedness to prove the convergence to 0. I thought what you mean here is that without the boundedness we can not have $\{Au_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence and so we can not define the extension. Is it?

Comment: Indeed suppose we have an extension $\tilde{D}$, if $u=\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n$, then $\tilde{D} u=\lim_{n\to \infty} D u_n$. If we let $u_n=e^{-nx}$ and n goes to infinity, then $u=0$. Hence, we should have $D u=0$. But $\|\tilde{D} u\|=\|\lim_{n\to \infty } D u_n\|=\infty. $, which shows that the extension does not work.